# Fit and predict linear regression for each row in the database in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, regression

Good evening everyone, I am new to Python and I'm trying to learn by reproducing a model I have on Excel

I need to replicate the "TREND" function to fit a small linear model between two extreme points, let's say

*A = (1, 0.15) B= (5,0.2)*

and predicting using a given value (let's say 4.2).

For the purpose of this code I need to fit a model for each line of my database. All x values are x_1=1 and x_2=5, while y values are different in each line.

I tried using LinearRegression() and model.predict from the sklearn.linear_model package this way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = {'New_x':[5, 2.1, 4.5, 3.0],
        'X1':[1, 1, 1, 1],
        'X2':[5, 5, 5, 5],
        'Y1':[0.15, 0.7, 1.35, 0.2],
        'Y2':[0.2, 0.85, 1.55, 0.4]}  

df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=["1","2","3","4"])

model=LinearRegression().fit(df[["X1","X2"]],df[["Y1","Y2"]])
prediction=model.predict(df["New_x"].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

But I'm getting this error

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-da83cb57bf4a> in <module>()
     18 
     19 model=LinearRegression().fit(df[["X1","X2"]],df[["Y1","Y2"]])
---> 20 prediction=model.predict(df["New_x"].values.reshape(-1,1))
     21 
     22 #model = LinearRegression().fit(SEC_ERBA_sample[["Vertex1","Vertex2"]], SEC_ERBA_sample[["SENIOR_1Y","SENIOR_5Y"]])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    254             Returns predicted values.
    255         """
--> 256         return self._decision_function(X)
    257 
    258     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    239         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    240         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 241                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    242 
    243     def predict(self, X):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    138         return ret
    139     else:
--> 140         return np.dot(a, b)
    141 
    142 

ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

So I presume that `LinearRegression().fit` is fitting a unique model based on the column values. Is there a way to fit and predict a linear regression for each row?

Comment: Will you please add the _full_ traceback to the question? It makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @user17242583 the full traceback is a bit complex, but I have added a representative example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using iterrow(). Still incomplete as I can't save the output, but I think I will open a separate and more focused question for that

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = {'New_x':[5, 2.1, 4.5, 3.0],
        'X1':[1., 1, 1, 1],
        'X2':[5., 5, 5, 5],
        'Y1':[0.15, 0.7, 1.35, 0.2],
        'Y2':[0.2, 0.85, 1.55, 0.4]}  

df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=["1","2","3","4"])
```

This final piece allows iterating the linear regression. Using iterrows() is not suggested as many operations can be run in different ways (including vectorization) but in this case I was not finding an alternative solution for this problem

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    model=LinearRegression().fit(np.array([row["X1"],row["X2"]]).reshape(-1,1),
                                 np.array([row["Y1"],row["Y2"]]))
    print(model.predict(row["New_x"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple code typo, but may be funded on a deeper conceptual problem, so I'll try to give you a broader answer.
The `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator#fit` trains a ML model by associating a set of features `X` to a set of ground-truth values `y`. In your example, you are training two multi-variable regression model to estimate the `Y1` and `Y2` variables taking `X1` and `X2` into consideration:

```py
model = LinearRegression().fit(df[["X1","X2"]], df[["Y1","Y2"]])
```

So the model learns to estimate these two variables taking **two** other variables into consideration.
During predicting, the model requires exactly variables (`X1` and `X2`) to be able to predict the values of interest.

```py
predictions = model.predict(df[["New_x1", "New_x2"]])
```

If the `New_x2` information is not available during test (predict) time, then you either have to estimate it as well or remove it from training altogether.

*A simple abstract example:* if a model was trained to estimate your preferred t-shirt size from your height and weight, you need to know both height and weight during test (predict) time to obtain the correct size estimation.